# Is there a list of photo printing services that use the Flickr API?

Tags: prints, flickr, iphone

Is there a list of known photo printing services that utilize the Flickr API so that images can be grabbed from your existing Flickr account rather than you having to create a separate account and re-uploading all of your images to the print-service's own web site?

Flickr endorses SnapFish, which people seem to find not the greatest option. However, I recently learned that there are services that will grab your images directly off of Flickr for you using the Flickr API. This is great, as it means I can keep my images in one spot. Apparently Adorama is one of these services. Is there a list of other options out there anywhere? I'd love to be able to try a few of them out.

A bonus would be if said site also would accept photos being uploaded/submitted from an iOS app.

A super extra special bonus would be if said iOS app could also have the print site grab files directly from Flickr.

The end result is being able to have a central repository (flickr) but easily get prints made without having to manually replicate the repository that I have taken the time to set up on flickr.

Comment: I have seen some pieces of what you are asking for in iOS apps, but nothing that really fulfills most of what you are asking for. I do not think something like this exists. I think what you are doing with Flickr is too obscure to justify this development, but that is just my opinion, and obviously at least 1 person finds it useful :)

Comment: It seems that much of the purpose of Flickr is to be a central location to store your photos. Sort of 'the cloud' before 'the cloud' was even a term. It's just a bit frustrating that, when it comes to printing the photos, the concept of the cloud is ignored.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is [**a list**](http://www.flickr.com/services/apps/tags/print/), maintained by flickr, in their Services section, using the tag "print". Or [**search**](http://www.flickr.com/services/apps/search/?q=print) the apps with "print".

- [Photoworks SF](http://www.flickr.com/services/apps/57157/)
- [Imagekind](http://www.flickr.com/services/apps/26128/)
- [moo.com](http://www.flickr.com/services/apps/72157618817103382/)
- [Tiny Prints](http://www.flickr.com/services/apps/72157607832943237/)
- [QOOP](http://www.flickr.com/services/apps/1141/)
- ...etc...

Answer (score 2):

Here are some of the services I could find that can print from Flickr:

- [Photobox](http://www.photobox.co.uk/): [Top UK printing service uploads from flickr](http://www.photobox.co.uk/my/album/upload/flickr)
- [AdoramaPix](http://www.adoramapix.com/): [Supports importing from flickr](http://forums.adoramapix.com/entries/202121-importing-from-flickr)
- [Zoomin.com](http://www.zoomin.com/Home): [Photo prints page describes import from Flickr](http://www.zoomin.com/Photo-Prints)

Zoomin.com took digging through to the 4th page of search results on Bing. There are a LOT of irrelevant results when trying to search for printers that support import from flickr, but I would assume that there are more than three (four, counting SnapFish) printers that support it.

Comment: Yes, it's odd. I'd think think would be a feature to promote, but maybe it's not as useful as I'm thinking it is. Thanks for this list, though!